# apt-get doesnt download files from NFS location

Tags: apt, nfs

I have switched to unix from last 3 months and trying to understand install process and in particular apt-get.

I am able to successfully install and download the packages when I configure my repository on http location in /etc/apt/sources.list file. e.g.

```
deb http://web.myspqce.com/u/eng/rose/debian-mirror-squeeze-amd64/mirror/ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
```

This command will download(/var/cache/apt/archive) and install the package when i use apt-get install

When I change the source location to file instead of http(nfs mount point), the package is getting installed but NOT getting downloaded in /var/cache/apt/archive.

```
deb file:/deb_repository/debian-mirror-squeeze-amd64/mirror/ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
```

Please let me know if there is any configuration or settings that i have to make to let apt-get to both download and install package when i use (nfs)file:/ instead of http:/ in sources.list.

To achieve this, I can use apt-get --downlaod-only and then use apt-get install for both download and install in two separate calls, but I want to know why package is not getting downloaded with apt-get install but only getting installed when used with file:/ in sources.list

Comment: One update. I cannot even do download only when I use nfs location. e.g. With apt-get --download-only install <package> the command says downloading, but it doesnt actually download the package with the file:/ in the sources.list file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. But as per man page, file:/ options are mainly used when we use nfs mount points. For CDROMs there is separate option as cdrom:/ I will try with deb-copy and update my results here.

Answer (score 1):

`deb-file` is mainly used for CDROMs, so downloading them into a cache makes no sense.

Use `deb-copy` instead.

Source:

```
$ man sources.list
```